# Raising and Lowering Indices of Basis Tensors?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

Can you raise and lower the indices of basis vectors and dual basis vectors? I know I can write

$$V^\mu = g^{\mu\nu} V_\nu $$

but can I also write

$$\vec{V} = V^\alpha \hat{e}_\alpha = V_\beta \hat{e}^\beta?$$

Comment: That depends on what your definition of $\hat{e}^\beta$ is. I think there's a standard one but I'm not too sure, so I ask just in case. Also, I really suggest learning some LaTeX to type the equations.

Answer (score 2):

The equation $$\vec{V} = V^\alpha \hat{e}_\alpha = V_\beta \hat{e}^\beta$$ does not make sense, you are equating two different objects, a vector and a covector. If you take a **finite** dimensional vector space, $V$, the **dual** space $V^*$ is the set of all linear functions that map elements of $V$ to the field over which it is defined.

The metric tensor is a special object that, when defined, provides a [bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) map between the elements of $V$ and $V^*$. That is, each element in $V$ has a **unique** covector in $V^*$ and the metric is a map that relates them, this is why you are allowed to mnemonically "raise" and "lower" indices with the metric (but not with any old rank-2 tensor).

If you pick a basis in $V$ you can also define a special basis in $V$* such that

$$\hat e^i(\tilde e_j)=\delta^i_j$$

Comment: Not that it changes the validity of the answer, but the definition you gave for dual space $V^*$ does actually work for the infinite dimensional case too.

Comment: Ah you're right, that remark is more relevant in the next paragraph.